# UIActionSheet customization using private API

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I need to add images on action sheet buttons so I used following code

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheetObject = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Follow Us" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:kCancel destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Twitter",@"Facebook",@"Blog",@"LinkedIn",nil];
[[[actionSheetObject valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageFromBundle:@"TwitterIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[[actionSheetObject valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:1] setImage:[UIImage imageFromBundle:@"FacebookIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[[actionSheetObject valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:2] setImage:[UIImage imageFromBundle:@"BlogIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[[actionSheetObject valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:3] setImage:[UIImage imageFromBundle:@"LinkedInIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[actionSheetObject showInView:self.view];
```

OutPut 
[image]

But My question is it the correct way to achieve this?
Means Apple will accept my app on appstore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99.9% is that Apple will accept this, because compiler will not detect no warnings about this, but  there is other problem, Apple can change the name of variables in the UIActionSheet, I mean, this code is risky, but definitely will work and pass the Apple validations.

Comment: P.S. this is not exactly private API, this is not API at all :), just some tricks to access some objects, in a not convenient way.

Comment: Thanks nil for your reply I know it will work just worry about appstore rejection.

Comment: Hi Nik, Apple accepted my application using above code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use private API's, if you want to put your app on AppStore. Apple will reject the app's that use private API's.

According to [UIActionSheet Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add
>   views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more
>   customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create
>   your own and present it modally with
>   presentViewController:animated:completion:.

As an alternative way you can use a customized `UIView` with these `UIButtons`. When it is displayed, you can disable the touch events of parent view, so that it will act same like action-sheet.

Here is an example: [Display a custom UIView like a UIActionSheet](https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/display-a-custom-uiview-like-a)

Comment: Thanks Midhun MP for your reply, the code which I used contains the private API?

Comment: @Vijay: there is no documented way of customizing the UIActionSheet. You just used the `_buttons` key to do that. That was not documented or public. Same like there are a lot of UIViewAnimations (Camera Iris, suction effect etc) available in ios, but not documented. One of my friends application got rejected because of using the 'not documented' methods.